# Code::blocks IDE: Reload files without asking about it

Tags: text-editors, ide, code-blocks

If a file has been changed externally, Code::Blocks the IDE always asks about it in a popup. It looks somewhat like this:

[image]

This gets tiresome when working with several editors, so is there a way to disable the popup? I've searched the both the "editor" and "environment" entries in "settings", but haven't found a way to disable is. There was one setting that made code::blocks not check for file changes at all, but that is not what I want.

Comment: Oh, thought that was obvious. Will do!

Comment: However, if you did not know what code::blocks is, then maybe this isn't the right place to ask?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have come across wrong. I assumed it was obvious because of programming context, and didn't mean *you* specifically but "if the general superuser user doesn't know".

Comment: What programming context was there beyond the filename in the screenshot you only added after I asked.  I could have done a Google search, I suppose, but thats more work on my end and leaves a question unclear :-)

Comment: You're right, I just didn't think that far. Guess I've spent too much time with programmers, or something. 

But nevertheless, yeah sure, I could just use a single editor, but that's why I'm asking here, not to have to do that. And it seems like such a simple feature; disabling a dialogue, so i'd be surprised if they did not have it?

Comment: Visual Studio, CVI, and Notepad++ all don't have an option like you describe.

Comment: Okay. Well, let's just hope COde::Blocks does.